# Mongoose: exclude not populated fields

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Considering the following schema:

```
var CarSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    name: {type: String}

});
```

and the following query:

```
var query = Car.find();
query.exec(function(err, cars) {

});
```

since i don't explicitly populate the 'user' field on the query, the list of returned cars are:

```
[
    {
       name : "Car1",
       user : "5852a36499a7a21aa0b6d600" 
    },

    {
       name : "Car2",
       user : "5852a39499a7a21aa0b6d603"
    }
]
```

Is there any way (or plugin) to remove unpopulated fields (like the user field in this example) from the query response at some root level (like the Schema level)? I don't want to use ***.select(-user)*** on all of my queries.

Remember: i just want to remove unpopulated fields. If i set ***.populate('user')*** on the query, i still want the 'user' field to be returned.